# DocumentFile on SDCard

Tags: android, android-sdcard

I make files on SDCard (android) with Object DocumentFile. All works good.
How to change Last Modified Timestamp on this files?

Object File with setLastModified() on SDCard not works.
Thanks Michal

Answer (score 0):

[setLastModified()](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=18624) is unreliable on Android which is limited to be compatible with limited devices in market only.